# Connect to WifiDirect on AndroidTV but keep using regular WIFI for internet

Tags: android, wifi, television, wifip2p

I'm building an app for androidTV, which is connected with the phone to send/receive data with WifiDirect

The problen is that when the TV conects to the phone it shows a message saying "wifi device connected" and It seems that the TV starts to use the phone's internet for everithing (instead of the proper wifi).

I would like to know how to connect to wifi Direct, but still using previos internet connection to navigate and download data
(the wifi connected device is just for send/receive data.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [Android Compatibility Definition Document 7.0](https://source.android.com/compatibility/7.0/android-7.0-cdd.html) lists having concurrent Wi-Fi and Wi-Fi Direct as *SHOULD* which means it isn't mandatory.

```
Section 7.4.2.1. Wi-Fi Direct

...

If a device implementation includes support for Wi-Fi Direct, then it:

* MUST report the hardware feature android.hardware.wifi.direct.
* MUST support regular Wi-Fi operation.
* SHOULD support concurrent Wi-Fi and Wi-Fi Direct operation.
```